# Powershell Scheduled Task Open Web Page to Execute Script

Tags: asp.net, powershell, windows-server-2008

In an effort to setup a "cron job" like scheduled task on Windows I've setup a Powershell script using code recommended via previous stackoverflow question.

I have some backups that I need to cleanup daily and delete old backups so I created a asp.net script to perform this task - the file name is BackupCleanup.aspx and I have confirmed that the ASP.net script does work when executed on its own by visiting the above url - I however cannot get it to execute using the Powershell script below.

The Powershell Script code I'm using is:

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://127.0.0.1/BackupCleanup.aspx")
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$response.Close()
```

I have created this file with a PS1 extension, it shows properly in my os (Windows 2008) - I have tried both manually executing this task by right clicking and choosing "Run with Powershell" and also have scheduled this as a task - both to no avail.

I cannot figure out why the script does not work - any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Powershell script I use to call up web pages using IE. Hopefully this will work for you as well.

```
Function NavigateTo([string] $url, [int] $delayTime = 100)
{
  Write-Verbose "Navigating to $url"

  $global:ie.Navigate($url)

  WaitForPage $delayTime
}

Function WaitForPage([int] $delayTime = 100)
{
  $loaded = $false

  while ($loaded -eq $false) {
    [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep($delayTime) 

    #If the browser is not busy, the page is loaded
    if (-not $global:ie.Busy)
    {
      $loaded = $true
    }
  }

  $global:doc = $global:ie.Document
}

Function SetElementValueByName($name, $value, [int] $position = 0) {
  if ($global:doc -eq $null) {
    Write-Error "Document is null"
    break
  }
  $elements = @($global:doc.getElementsByName($name))
  if ($elements.Count -ne 0) {
    $elements[$position].Value = $value
  }
  else {
    Write-Warning "Couldn't find any element with name ""$name"""
  }
}

Function ClickElementById($id)
{
  $element = $global:doc.getElementById($id)
  if ($element -ne $null) {
    $element.Click()
    WaitForPage
  }
  else {
    Write-Error "Couldn't find element with id ""$id"""
    break
  }
}

Function ClickElementByName($name, [int] $position = 0)
{
  if ($global:doc -eq $null) {
    Write-Error "Document is null"
    break
  }
  $elements = @($global:doc.getElementsByName($name))
  if ($elements.Count -ne 0) {
    $elements[$position].Click()
    WaitForPage
  }
  else {
    Write-Error "Couldn't find element with name ""$name"" at position ""$position"""
    break
  }
}

Function ClickElementByTagName($name, [int] $position = 0)
{
  if ($global:doc -eq $null) {
    Write-Error "Document is null"
    break
  }
  $elements = @($global:doc.getElementsByTagName($name))
  if ($elements.Count -ne 0) {
    $elements[$position].Click()
    WaitForPage
  }
  else {
    Write-Error "Couldn't find element with tag name ""$name"" at position ""$position"""
    break
  }
}

#Entry point

# Setup references to IE
$global:ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$global:ie.Navigate("about:blank")
$global:ie.visible = $true

# Call the page
NavigateTo "http://127.0.0.1/BackupCleanup.aspx"

# Release resources
$global:ie.Quit()
$global:ie = $null
```

Comment: Nice - I will test this out - do you know if this is safe to run as a scheduled task with no user logged in?

Comment: No go - I'm starting to wonder if its not the Powershell script, but something else - do you happen to know if there is a way I can step through a script to see if its working?

Comment: Have you checked your script permissions?

Comment: yea I can run the script outside Powershell and it functions properly, its weird becuase when I manually run the powershell script a black cmd box pops up and disappears real quick, but it doesn't appear to execute the script by visiting the URL in the code

Comment: That sounds like a pathing issue. Have you tried running the script from a plain old command prompt (the way a scheduled task would)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I manually opened powershell and executed my script and I received "WebPage.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.".

You have to allow scripts to run

Execute the below in PowerShell

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine